# Cannot make DataGridView to bind to data source more than once

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a Winforms GUI app. I have a list of simple class called `FinishedTests_Loops_DGV`. This list is being added in a different thread (timer thread). After new class is added to the list (inside timer thread), I call `updateLoopsDGV()` which invokes the `DataGridView` and updates it:

```
public void updateLoopsDGV()
{
    if (DGV_Loops.InvokeRequired)
    {
        DGV_Loops.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
        {
            DGV_Loops.DataSource = FinishedTests_Loops_DGV;
        });
    }
}
```

This works **only one time**, meaning that once first element is added to the list, I see the first line appears in `DataGridView`, but any further calls to `updateLoopsDGV()` do NOT add lines to `DataGridView`. I checked in the debugger that my list is, for example 4 elements long, and function is called, but I still only see 1 row in the `DataGridView`.

Even when I try to update the `DataGridView` by pressing on some button (in GUI thread):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DGV_Loops.DataSource = FinishedTests_Loops_DGV;
}
```

It still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show some code for the `FinishedTests_Loops_DGV` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataGridView` will not update, because you using same instance of list for setting `.DataSource`([DataGridView Reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,bf806e06bca7d88a))

Then `List<T>` does not support notifications of the changes in the collection.
`DataGridView` will never know about changes in the list

Use `BindingList<T>` instead, then it is enough to bind it to `DataSource` only once.
And added items will be automatically displayed in the `DataGridView`

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you are trying to set datasource improperly.

You say that `FinishedTests_Loops_DGV` is a class, and providing it as the `DataSource`. This is very strange as this is binding to the `Type` object, not the actual list.

I think that you should create a variable of `IEnumerable<FinishedTests_Loops_DGV>` and provide it as `DataSource`, something like this:

```
IEnumerable<FinishedTests_Loops_DGV> aList = ...; // actual data get
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DGV_Loops.DataSource = aList;
}
```

Comment: In the first line of question: _I have a list of simple class called `FinishedTests_Loops_DGV`_